# Sticky footer in scroll-y-container depending on height of content

Tags: html, css, sticky, sticky-footer

We have a container with `overflow-y:scroll` that must have a footer that is sticky (bottom 0) unless the content inside the scrolling container + the height (which is dynamic) of the footer are bigger than the containers height.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    This must stick to the bottom until .content is too long, then go below it
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

.content and .footer can have more or less content.

If possible, we do not want to use JS for this.

I created a fiddle here with several states: http://jsfiddle.net/bqvtf1zo/1/

Removing `position: absolute` on .footer solves it for case "little content" (see fiddle), but breaks the other 2 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You need to create a `flex` container.*** (Though there are other ways to hande this problem as well: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

For the container, set the `display` to `flex` and `flex-direction` to `column` and give the scrollable content a `flex` value of `1`. Remove positioning from footer, and there you have it.

This will cause the content to stretch to fill the height of the container if any is available, and it will cause the footer to be stuck to the bottom of the content.

*For implementation: Be sure to follow up on all the cross-browser issues with flexbox, such as prefixes and bugs. https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs*

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 205px;
  width: 200px;
}
.scroll{
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
   display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content{
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex:1;

}
.footer{
  background-color: #efefef;

}
```

```html
<h1>
 little content
</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    This must stick to the bottom until .content is too long, then go below it
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h1>
 large content
</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    12. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    13. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    This must stick to the bottom until .content is too long, then go below it
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
 large content with large footer
</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    6. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    7. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    8. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    12. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    13. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    This must stick to the bottom until .content is too long, then go further down<br>
    Some additional content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks promising. Let me try with my real code. Thanks so much so far!

Comment: If you like it, please consider a vote up and accept of my answer